# How to deploy a .net5 app to Google Cloud Appengine?

Tags: asp.net-core, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a .net 5 project to google app engine but it looks like there is an issue when I want to build with .net5 runtime.

Here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
service: api
# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Once I send the app to gcloud I get this error :

> Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-
> runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:f5552a5efdaf278a3124ea10fd1c96fg36b09fc9f98f9e620cbd71279797576b3f
> Step #0: No .deps.json file found for the app

Something weird is that when I write "dotnet --version" in the gcloud terminal it respond with : 3.1.407
Is there a way to update the dotnet runtime and sdk from google cloud ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally downloaded the Google cloud tool for visual studio and apparently, .net 5 is not supported in app engine for the moment.

> Step #0: The app requires .NET Core runtime version 5 which is not supported at this time.

Comment: App Engine flex deploys containers. While Google provides runtimes for multiple runtime versions, you can use any Dockerfile that has an HTTP server listening to port 8080  Using Dockerfiles adds some complexity but provides more flexibility You should be able to deploy an (ASP)  .NET 5 app that way

Comment: See this; https://www.google.com/amp/s/cloudblog.withgoogle.com/topics/developers-practitioners/net-50-google-cloud/amp/ It is for Cloud Run but the principle is almost identical  You'll want to ensure the server runs on 8080

Comment: I am actually deploying with cloudrun and everything works fine. I have tried to deploy to appengine flex with a dockerfile in the silution but it stops me because there is a dockerfile and should be only an app.yaml. I will try again for flex but i'm pretty sure it doesn't work.

Comment: Cloud Run's good but I'm very confident it will work on App Engine if you'd prefer to use App Engine. You'd need to use `runtime: custom` so that the tool picks up the Dockerfile. See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart#code_review The only hard requirement is that the container listen on 8080 but this is very similar to the Cloud Run requirement for `PORT` so I think you just need to tweak `app.yaml`